# How do you play two chords at once on piano?

Tags: piano

[image]

How would I play both of the chords in the bass clef at the same time? I'm self taught, and I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: use the damper pedal

Answer (score 1):

This notation looks rather silly to me. There is no way you can sustain the bottom D for the whole bar, and repeat it at the same time!

In practice, just ignore the whole-note bottom D. Hold down the other two whole-notes, and play the 8ths and dotted 8ths. You play the first two 8ths at the same time as the whole notes.

Comment: That sort of thing is not that unusual in piano notation. It indicates that the note should be sustained throughout the duration of the whole note while also being re-struck for the eighth notes, which implies that the damper or sostenuto pedal must be used to play it. I am familiar with an example from _Gymnopedie no. 1._

Comment: @BraddSzonye I'm familiar with it as well, but it's still silly. If the whole note D was intended to mean that, either (1) why isn't there a whole note F#, or (2) how do you play the F#'s differently from the D's? The notation of Gymnopedie #1 (at least in the first edition) doesn't make *that* silly mistake! I get the feeling the OP's example isn't a professionally produced score, otherwise the tie on the D wouldn't collide with the other notes in the bar. Assuming that any music score from the web "means what it says" is a bit risky.